# why the sqlsrv_fetch_array doens't get the first row of the select query

Tags: php, sql

I am using this select

```
$sql1=" SELECT pole FROM Table1 WHERE dva='d'";
```

and it should return all for elements from the table ( because in the field "dva" they all have 'd')  and using this function to do it

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($st)) {
 // echo $row[0]."<br />";
print_r($row);
}
```

here is the result I get, it starts from the second row and so on...

```
Array ( 
    [0] => testxz2 
    [pole] => testxz2 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => some data 
    [pole] => some data 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => some data 
    [pole] => some data 
)
```

before I tried this and this got me the row number 1 and the other rows I got from the upper code,

```
   while($pole=sqlsrv_get_field($st,0)){echo $pole;}
```

Comment: did you try running this select in sql server client?

Comment: sorry did not understand, how to run in sql server client ?

Comment: usually, databases have native clients that can be installed on your machine and you can use it to run queries on the DB without writing code. like MySql and phpmyadmin. you can try this: http://www.dbvis.com/ , or this: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

Comment: so run the query in the GUI client and see what results you get.

Comment: Just did it it get the result as it should all 4 rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can u put the whole code before the fetch call

JUST edit the part before:

```
   if( sqlsrv_fetch( $st ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

I think here is the error because you are fetching the first element and the second while u use to fetch all rows is missing the first because is already fetch... Try to use your `while` loop before the first fetch..

Comment: $sql1=" SELECT pole FROM Table1 WHERE dva='d'";
$st=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql1);
if( $st === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


 
}
//$te=sqlsrv_fetch($st);
/*if( sqlsrv_fetch( $st ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}*/

while($name=sqlsrv_get_field($st,0)){echo $name;}